Best way to crate a simple blog website using using Next.js (MDX or Data fetching)?
I want to create a blog website to write life and code blog, with the rsc and supported meta content like ranking with the google and apple bot with dynamic OG image.
next.js is the framework provides lot of features, but want to create a dynamic manifest as well as dynamic meta data.

I am looking for the best way to create a blog website, I am definitely create a lots of blogs but here is the catch, I want to create a website with the dynamic content with lazy loading. The blog should have updated html content as well as sandbox code and I want to update my blogs with the content. also want to highlight code with the updated line.


I saw other developers creating blog website with using rehyper tool. and also fetching content from mdx file using fs module
I need your suggestions to create a blog with the dyanamic content.

I would suggest you to go with Next.js. It is a React framework that supports Server Side Rendering (SSR), which means the blogs will be rendered on the server hence improving SEO and performance.
Moreover, Next.js allows you to create API routes within your application, allowing you to perform CRUD operations without needing a dedicated backend. As you have mentioned the content needs to be dynamic so I guess using these APIs can really help you with that.
If you want to learn more about this framework and all the pros and cons it comes with, you can refer to their documentation:
Next.js Documentation
